# No push notifications on React Native standalone android build using expo-notifications package

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

Current project:
SDK Version - 39.0.0
Android standalone build

Hello there!
I having no push notifications on standalone build, what i did:

- added firebase account with app info provided in app.json
- putted `google-services.json` into app root and added path in `expo.android.googleServicesFile` in `app.json`
- added key with `expo push:android:upload --api-key <my-key>` and tried to change it with a new one
- added android push notification channel in application
  Just in case, tried to send push notification on device token from `getDevicePushTokenAsync()` directly with firebase endpoint using my key and everything works.

long story short - did everything according [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/). In case of certain changes, expo.io needs FCM for sending push notifications via expo packages.

sending push notification on token from `getExpoPushTokenAsync()` doesn’t work at all except iPhone build.

Could you please help me with my problem? maybe i lost something in my steps to make my push notification work properly?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem?