# Push notifications via FCM on standalone expo android build not triggering addNotificationResponseReceivedListener()

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

SDK Version: 39.0.3
Android standalone build

I was reading documentation regarding sending push notifications over FCM because of unsuccessful tryings to [achieve expo push notifications working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146092/no-push-notifications-on-react-native-standalone-android-build-using-expo-notifi), I tried to make push notifications trough `getDevicePushTokenAsync()` and everything goes quite well, until I needed to put an event listener.

So, I put `addNotificationResponseReceivedListener()` and it works well on iOS but not on Android. Yeah, documentation says to put `experienceId` into data object in FCM request and I did, but still no result. Also, there is no such field in any payload listed in [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) and anyways, still no successful result on push notifications in any way that I tried.

Getting really frustrated on idea of working push notifications, I hope I lost something in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `app.json`, we turned off OTA updates and it causes problems with push notifications.

[Here's](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-notifications-no-experience-found-for-id/43282/15) an answer on expo.io forum

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"useNextNotificationsApi": true` under the android key in your app.json file. it worked for me

[image]